# How to bake an object?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I have a version 2.90 on blender.I was creating a barrel and I UV unwrapped it and made a new object and named it 'barrel' as well.Now I don't find any option which says bake or anything related to it..
Anyone knows how to do this?Please paste a picture for better understanding[image: This is the barrel I made and the UV unwrap..]

Comment: could you explain a bit more what your final goal is, please

Comment: I wanna bake my object basically

Comment: i was watching the tutorial of Brackeys he had a lower version but I have  version 2.90.He baked his object but I don't see anything..

Comment: Baking basically involves transferring information to a texture. In order to help you, we'll need to understand precisely what information you're trying to transfer. For example, are you trying to bake normal information from a high-poly model? Or are you trying to make the material colors?

Comment: Bake is in the Properties > Render panel, but you need to be in Cycles, is it the case?

Comment: Yes,Thanks i'll try this also I don't know this thing thanks u teach me a new thing

Answer (score 1):

Baking is only avaliable in the Cycles Render Engine.
Switching to Cycles in Render Properties gives you the needed Baking panel.

[image]

Comment: Ohk bro thanks I'll try this